# Making a Nonblocking socket for WinSocks and *nix

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, sockets, nonblocking

In C/C++, how would I turn a blocking socket into a non blocking socket in both WinSocks and *nix; so that select() would work correctly. You can use the pre-processor for the platform specific code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On linux:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

[Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738573.aspx):

```
u_long on = 1;
ioctlsocket(fd, FIONBIO, &on);
```

Answer (score 5):

select() is supposed to work on *blocking* sockets.  It returns when a read() would return immediately, which is always the case with non-blocking sockets.